# TensorFlow gradients example

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have the following code to compute an example of gradients using TensorFlow-

```
# z = f(x, y) = 2*x - y
# Partial derivative of dz/dx = 2; dz/dy = -1
# Initialize x and y variables-                                         
x = tf.Variable([1], dtype = tf.int32)
y = tf.Variable([2], dtype = tf.int32)
z = tf.subtract(2 * x, y)

# Define gradient operation-
grad = tf.gradients(z, [x, y])


# Initialize TensorFlow session-
sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize all variables-
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Compute gradient defined above-
res_grad = sess.run(grad)

# Close the session-
sess.close()
```

But the line-

```
res_grad = sess.run(grad)
```

Gives the following error-

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 res = sess.run(grad)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       948     try:
>       949       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>   --> 950                          run_metadata_ptr)
>       951       if run_metadata:
>       952         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>   1156     # Create a fetch handler to take care of the structure of
>   fetches.    1157     fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(
>   -> 1158         self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)    1159     1160     # Run request and get
>   response.
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in **init**(self, graph, fetches, feeds, feed_handles)
>       472     """
>       473     with graph.as_default():
>   --> 474       self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
>       475     self._fetches = []
>       476     self._targets = []
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in for_fetch(fetch)
>       262     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
>       263       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
>   --> 264       return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
>       265     elif isinstance(fetch, collections.Mapping):
>       266       return _DictFetchMapper(fetch)
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in **init**(self, fetches)
>       371     """
>       372     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
>   --> 373     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
>       374     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
>       375
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in (.0)
>       371     """
>       372     self._fetch_type = type(fetches)
>   --> 373     self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
>       374     self._unique_fetches, self._value_indices = _uniquify_fetches(self._mappers)
>       375
>
> ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in for_fetch(fetch)
>       259     if fetch is None:
>       260       raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r' % (fetch,
>   --> 261                                                                  type(fetch)))
>       262     elif isinstance(fetch, (list, tuple)):
>       263       # NOTE(touts): This is also the code path for namedtuples.
>
> TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type

What's going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're passing integer tensors. Use floats and it should work.

```
x = tf.Variable([1.0])
y = tf.Variable([2.0])
z = tf.subtract(2 * x, y)

# Define gradient operation-
grad = tf.gradients(z, [x, y])

# Initialize TensorFlow session-
sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize all variables-
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Compute gradient defined above-
res_grad = sess.run(grad)

print (res_grad) # Output = [array([ 2.], dtype=float32), array([-1.], dtype=float32)]

# Close the session-
sess.close()
```

This was changed in [#16504](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16504). Allowing gradients on integer tensors was causing incorrectness in tf.while_loop, and there was no satisfactory way to resolve them without this change.